# What are fast XML parsers for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I am using Nokogiri which works for small documents well. But for a 180KB HTML file I have to increase the process stack size, via `ulimit -s`, and the parsing and XPath queries take a long time.

Are there faster methods available using a stock Ruby distribution?

I am getting used to XPath, but the solution does not necessarily need to support XPath.

The criteria are:

1. Fast to write.
2. Fast execution.
3. Robust resulting parser.

Comment: nokogiri is the fastest gem right now

Comment: I found ox better than nokogiri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nokogiri is based on libxml2, which is one of the fastest XML/HTML parsers in any language. It is written in C, but there are bindings in many languages.

The problem is that the more complex the file, the longer it takes to build a complete DOM structure in memory. Creating a DOM is slower and more memory-hungry than other parsing methods (generally the entire DOM must fit into memory). XPath relies on this DOM.

SAX is often what people turn to for speed or for large documents that don't fit into memory. It is more event driven: it notifies you of a start element, end element, etc, and you write handlers to react to them. It's a bit of a pain because you end up keeping track of state yourself (e.g. which elements you're "inside").

There is a middle ground: some parsers have a "pull parsing" capability where you have a cursor-like navigation. You still visit each node sequentially, but you can "fast-forward" to the end of an element you're not interested in. It's got the speed of SAX but a better interface for many uses. I don't know if Nokogiri can do this for HTML, but I'd look into its [Reader API](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html) if you're interested.

Note that Nokogiri is also very lenient with malformed markup (such as real-world HTML) and this alone makes it a very good choice for HTML parsing.

Comment: nokogiri is not too fast as expected. right now I have an issue with parsing large XML file. I dont really know how many records are in the file but the size of file is 7.2mb. so when i try to parse - nokogiri hangs up. and reaches memory leak

Comment: I'd be interested in this ability.  _"fast-forward" to the end of an element you're not interested in_  does Nokogiri SAX have this though?

Comment: @HarryWood SAX as an API is about as plain-vanilla as you can get. However, check out the gem [saxerator](https://github.com/soulcutter/saxerator) which uses SAX under the hood and will essentially fast forward to an element you're looking for and enumerate the items there.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the Ox gem. It is faster than LibXML and Nokogiri and supports in memory parsing as well as SAX callback parsing. Full disclosure, I wrote it.

---

In the performance comparison http://www.ohler.com/software/thoughts/Blog/Entries/2011/9/21_XML_with_Ruby.html both a DOM (in memory) and SAX (callback) parsers are compared.

Comment: Hm, do you want to add a link to it?

Comment: I've used Ox, and I've been very pleased with it (https://github.com/ohler55/ox)

Comment: Where can I have some more documentation on using like nodes , cdata in ox gem?

Comment: Does this work with HTML? How well does it handle real-world (i.e. invalid) HTML?

Comment: Mansoor, just have a quick look in the source.

Comment: I ported a Java program (using JAXP) to Ruby 2.0 with Ox.  The Ruby version was 4-5 times faster on the same files, and the code for getting cdata out was much simpler (didn't require a lexical parser).  I was very impressed with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Link to Ox is http://rubygems.org/gems/ox. A discussion of performance differences: http://www.ohler.com/software/thoughts/Blog/Entries/2011/9/21_XML_with_Ruby.html

Comment: I suggest that you merge your two user accounts (which are called the same?!?) and your two answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that for larger XML documents DOM parsing is not very performant. This is because the parser has to build an in-memory map of the structure of the XML document.

The other approach that generally requires a smaller memory footprint is to use an event-driven SAX parser.

Nokogiri has full support for SAX.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, [Oga](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/oga) may be better suited as a *fast enough* XML parsers for Ruby with a much better interface and faster installation time.