# extracting path within a string using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rake

I have written a ruby script where I iterate through folders, and search for file names ending with ".xyz" . Within these files I search then for lines which have the following structure:

```
<ClCompile Include="..\..\..\Projects\Project_A\Applications\Modules\Sources\myfile.c"/>
```

This works so far with the script:

```
def parse_xyz_files
  files = Dir["./**/*.xyz"]
  files.each do |file_name|
    puts file_name
    File.open(file_name) do |f|
      f.each_line { |line|
        if line =~ /<ClCompile Include=/
          puts "Found #{line}"
        end 
      }
  end
  end
  end
```

Now I would like to extract only the string between double quotes, in this example:

```
..\..\..\Projects\Project_A\Applications\Modules\Sources\myfile.c
```

I'm trying to do it with something like this (with match method):

```
def parse_xyz_files
  files = Dir["./**/*.xyz"]
  files.each do |file_name|
    puts file_name
    File.open(file_name) do |f|
      f.each_line { |line|
        if line =~ /<ClCompile Include=/.match(/"([^"]*)"/)
            puts "Found #{line}"
          end

      }
  end
  end
  end
```

The regular expression is so far ok (checked with rubular). Any idea how to do it in a simple way? I'm relative new to ruby.

Comment: The files you are trying to parse look like XML files, so I suggest to use an XML parser (eventually a pull parser if files are large) instead of a regex approach. take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036659/what-are-fast-xml-parsers-for-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
line = '<ClCompile Include="..\..\..\Projects\Project_A\Applications\Modules\Sources\myfile.c"/>'

path = line.scan(/".*"/).first
```

or in the case if your `<CICompile>` tag can have some other attributes then:

```
path = line.scan(/Include="(.*)"/).first.first
```

But using an XML parser is definitely a much better idea.

Comment: This works fine! As you said I will use further the XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse the XML and not regex.

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = '<foo><bar><ClCompile Include="..\..\..\Projects\Project_A\Applications\Modules\Sources\myfile.c"/></bar></foo>'
document = Nokogiri::XML xml
d.xpath('//ClCompile/@Include').text
```